# Java JsonObject: Converting to invalid string

Tags: java, json, gson, objectmapper

I am using objectMapper to convert object as string. While converting mappper is creating invalid string. How can I keep `JsonNode`/`JsonObject` string intact while using object mapper.

JsonObject:

```
{
    "provision": " purpose of usefuleness.\n\n shall not use personal-provided facilities.\n\nWe shall not be required to pay you. 
}
```

Is Converted to

```
{
        "provision": " purpose of usefuleness.
 \shall not use personal-provided facilities.
\We shall not be required to pay you. 
}
```

Used:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValuesAsString(json);
```

How can keep the original String intact.
with

```
new JsonObject(String)
```

or
when using

```
 new ObjectMapper().writeValuesAsString(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unquote special character \n

```
      String body = "{\"provision\" : \"purpose of usefuleness.\\n\\n shall not use personal-provided facilities.\\n\\nWe shall not be required to pay you.\"}";
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String result = null;
      try {
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(body);
        result = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(result);
```

```
{
  "provision" : "purpose of usefuleness.\n\n shall not use personal-provided facilities.\n\nWe shall not be required to pay you."
}
```

Comment: Sorry tried but not worked.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever What the result? Error?

Comment: No Error, but i saw same result as my input.